# Controller not getting post data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using jquery UI datepicker to send the `from` and `to` dates to the controller.  My problem is that the controller is not getting the post data.

In my View:

```js
to_date.datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function (selectedDate, inst) {
        if (from_date.datepicker("getDate") > to_date.datepicker("getDate")) {
        // error check
        } else {
            var from = from_date.val();
            var to = selectedDate;

            var data = {
                FromDate: from,
                ToDate: to
            };

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'View',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                data: jsonData
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In my Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DorView(string dates)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        // Will die on this line because dates is empty
        DatePicker JsonDate = js.Deserialize<DatePicker>(dates);

        return Json(dates);
    }

    return Json(dates);
}
```

Comment: @SeanThoman I left my debug statements out of the post, but 'dates' on the server side is empty (called right before the serializer is initialized). On the client side, I can see the JSON being posted so I don't think it's the Deseralizer in this case.

Comment: You're right, I misread initially so deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to manually perform JSON deserialization in your controller. Simply use a view model and leave the default model binder do the job.

So define a view model

```
public class Dates
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

and have your controller action take this view model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DorView(Dates dates)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something with dates.FromDate and dates.ToDate

        return Json(dates);
    }

    return Json(dates);
}
```

Comment: This was part of the problem. My JSON string was not being constructed correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a key value pair with key named `dates`.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'View',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            data: "dates=" + jsonData
        });
```